# Visualizing topological deformation and quantum mechanical interference

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, interference, topological-field-theory

In section VI.1 of Zee's QFT, he says that for indistinguishable hard core particles in 2D, when comparing trajectories with different winding numbers:

> Since the classes cannot be deformed into each other, the corresponding amplitudes cannot interfere quantum mechanically

I know that homotopy classes are topologically distinct, but I'm having trouble linking that abstract fact to concrete intuition in this context -- especially since I've never seen this connection between topology and interference before. (Except in the Aharonov-Bohm effect, which just adds a phase shift that doesn't prevent interference.)

What does topological distinctness have to do with interference here? I'd especially appreciate an explanation that includes visual intuition rather than being purely algebraic.

Answer (score 0):

Mathematically, suppose you have two particles, if you keep them still, you will get two parallel lines in space-time. And if you move one around the other, you will get a vertical line (if time is the vertical direction) and a line winding around the vertical line. In the 2+1 dimension, these two are not homotopy equivalent (because one is winding around the other). While in the 3+1 dimension, these two configurations are homotopy equivalent (you can unlink the knot in the 3rd dimension of space).

Physically, two homotopy equivalent worldlines are thought to be the same, because due to the uncertainty principle you cannot tell which path the electrons experienced. So in 3d space, swapping two particles twice is equivalent to moving one particle around the other and moreover, is equivalent to not moving them. So each swap of particles will give you either a $+1$ or $-1$ phase, which corresponds to boson and fermion respectively. However, in 2d space, moving one particle around the other is no longer equivalent to not moving them. So you may get any phase.

I think by "can interfere quantum mechanically", Zee means these two configurations are equivalent in QM.